# alternatives to ms chart control?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

We're using the MS Chart for .net, but encountering the "image not found" problem for which there doesn't seem to be a solution.

Are there any alternatives for generating simple charts?

Comment: What is the  the "image not found" problem?

Comment: Some images simply don't work.  No rhyme or reason that anyone can determine, apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google charts are awesome. (http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/)

There is also a [C# library available](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/) to help generate the URLS needed for the charts

Comment: The output is just an image, so you literally just use an image tag to render the chart.  The browser will print it just like any other image.

Comment: Have you used in a secure site - i.e. using https?

Comment: I've not used it with https, but a quick look at the forums suggests that you can use https instead of http on the chart URL, but it may be flaky.  If you use http from your https site you'll get the "There are secure and non-secure elements" warning.  You could maybe set up something on the server side to call through to the google APIs, but then that means your server is going to be making requests to render charts for everyone.  Its worth trying your charts over https and see how things go.

Comment: I just tried loading the js lib with https and it seemed to work fine, using google.visualization.charttype().draw

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experiences with [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/).

Comment: If your looking for a reporting solution, XtraReports is the way to go, no question.

Comment: no, this is just a simple bar chart on a web page.  I didn't think it would be that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[Fusion charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/). They also have a [free edition](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/Default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik Radcharts are very powerful...it can handle simple to very complex charts.

It's very easy to setup simple charts...just a few lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Visiblox or Visifire or DDD. all of them are great.